# Magento - incorrect Origin Country

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9, bulkupdate

When our Magento shop was launched 5 years ago, apparently, the Origin Country under System --> Configuration --> Shipping Settings was set (default) to **Canada**. Our shop is located in **the Netherlands**.

If we change the country from California to the Netherlands, all our catalog prices are updated to incorrect prices.

How can we solve this?

Do we need to run an SQL bulk price update in our shop or is there an easier way?

Thanks in advance.

*(see step 4 in this article: http://my.kualo.com/knowledgebase/?kbcat=0&article=519)*